# Regresar a inicio de programa después de un "case" cumplido

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, while

Hola tengo el siguiente código, despues de que se cumplen las diferentes opciones como le hago para regresar al menu principal

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int entrada;
   Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);   
   do{ 

       System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");
       System.out.println("1. Crear lista");
       System.out.println("2. Insertar antes del nodo especifico");
       System.out.println("3. Vizualizar");
       System.out.println("4. Eliminar antes del nodo especifico");
       System.out.println("5. Salir del programa");
       entrada =opcion.nextInt();
    }while(entrada>5 || entrada <1 );

    List<String> ejemploLista = new ArrayList();

    switch (entrada){
        case 1:  
            int s2;

            do{
               System.out.println("Ingresa el primer nodo que se agregara: ");
               Scanner crear = new Scanner(System.in);
               String nodorecibido = crear.nextLine();
               ejemploLista.add(nodorecibido);
               System.out.println("¿Deseas ingresar otro nodo? S/N ");
               System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
               Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
              s2=s.nextInt();

       }while (s2 == 1);
       break;

       case 2:  
           System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 2");
           break;

      case 3:  
          System.out.println(ejemploLista);
          break;  

      case 4:  
          System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 4");
          break; 
    }  
  }
}
```

me falta programar las otras opciones pero lo que me interesa es saber como regresar al menu principal despues de que cada una de las opciones sean cumplidas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es extraer tus menús a funciones externas, de esta manera puedes aprovecharte de varias **ventajas** como:

1. **Reutilización de código** (podemos volver a llamar al menú principal sin necesidad de escribir más código)
2. **Simplificación de código** (El main y su switch se simplifica bastante). Más entendible y mantenible.

Un ejemplo (reestructuración de tu código) es:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EjemploMenu {

    public EjemploMenu() {}

    public int executeMainMenu() {
        int entrada;
        Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);   

        do{ 

           System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");
           System.out.println("1. Crear lista");
           System.out.println("2. Insertar antes del nodo especifico");
           System.out.println("3. Vizualizar");
           System.out.println("4. Eliminar antes del nodo especifico");
           System.out.println("5. Salir del programa");
           entrada =opcion.nextInt();
        }while(entrada>5 || entrada <1 );


        return entrada;
    }

    public List<String> executeCase1Menu() {

        int s2;
        List<String> ejemploLista = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner crear= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{

           System.out.println("Ingresa el primer nodo que se agregara: ");

           String nodorecibido = crear.nextLine();
           ejemploLista.add(nodorecibido);
           System.out.println("¿Deseas ingresar otro nodo? S/N ");
           System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
           s2=s.nextInt();

        }while (s2 == 1);

        return ejemploLista;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
           int entrada;
           EjemploMenu ejemploMenu = new EjemploMenu();

           entrada = ejemploMenu.executeMainMenu();
           List<String> ejemploLista = new ArrayList<String>();

           while(entrada!=5) {
                switch (entrada){
                    case 1:  
                      ejemploLista = ejemploMenu.executeCase1Menu();
                      entrada = ejemploMenu.executeMainMenu();
                      break;

                   case 2:  
                      System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 2");
                      //Do something for case 2
                      entrada = ejemploMenu.executeMainMenu();
                      break;

                  case 3:  
                      System.out.println(ejemploLista);
                      entrada = ejemploMenu.executeMainMenu();
                      break;  

                  case 4:  
                      System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 4");
                      //Do something for case 4
                      entrada = ejemploMenu.executeMainMenu();
                      break; 
                }
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, me sirvió mucho tu re ordenamiento de código es mas optimo para lo que deseo realizar, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Una posible manera sería esta:

```
Integer opcioneMenu = seleccionarOpcionMenu();

while (opcionMenu != 5) {
  ejecutarAccion(opcionMenu);
  seleccionarOpcionMenu();
}

return;
```

Así puedes extraer la funcionalidad a dos métodos, para que sea más mantenible:

```
public Integer seleccionarOpcionMenu() {
   do{ 
      Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");
      System.out.println("1. Crear lista");
      System.out.println("2. Insertar antes del nodo especifico");
      System.out.println("3. Vizualizar");
      System.out.println("4. Eliminar antes del nodo especifico");
      System.out.println("5. Salir del programa");
      Integer entrada = opcion.nextInt();
   }while(entrada>5 || entrada <1 );
   opcion.close();
   return entrada;
}


public void ejecutarAccion(Integer opcion) {    
   case 1:  
    int s2;   
    do{
          System.out.println("Ingresa el primer nodo que se agregara: ");
          Scanner crear = new Scanner(System.in);
          String nodorecibido = crear.nextLine();
          ejemploLista.add(nodorecibido);
          System.out.println("¿Deseas ingresar otro nodo? S/N ");
          System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          s2=s.nextInt();

    }while (s2 == 1);
    break;

    case 2:  System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 2");
    break;

    case 3:  System.out.println(ejemploLista);
    break;

    case 4:  System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 4");
    break;


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade un do while que te recorra todo lo que quieres realizar y ponle la condicion de que hasta que no pulse 5 no salga del programa

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int entrada;
   Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);
do{   
  do{ 

System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");
System.out.println("1. Crear lista");
System.out.println("2. Insertar antes del nodo especifico");
System.out.println("3. Vizualizar");
System.out.println("4. Eliminar antes del nodo especifico");
System.out.println("5. Salir del programa");
entrada =opcion.nextInt();
}while(entrada>5 || entrada <1 );

List<String> ejemploLista = new ArrayList();

switch (entrada){
    case 1:  
    int s2;

     do{
          System.out.println("Ingresa el primer nodo que se agregara: ");
          Scanner crear = new Scanner(System.in);
          String nodorecibido = crear.nextLine();
          ejemploLista.add(nodorecibido);
          System.out.println("¿Deseas ingresar otro nodo? S/N ");
          System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          s2=s.nextInt();

    }while (s2 == 1);
    break;

    case 2:  System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 2");
    break;

    case 3:  System.out.println(ejemploLista);
    break;

    case 4:  System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 4");
    break;


   }  
   }
}while(entrada!=5)
   }
```

Comment: Sorry por el texto mal formateado pero no se ponerlo bien desde aqui

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas haciendo es terminar cada bloque cuando se llame por eso es que termina el programa cuando lo ejecutas, he agarrado tu codigo y lo he hecho de tal forma que sirva como quieres.Aqui te dejo el codigo para que lo copies y pegues. Espero que te sirva:

```
package ejemplo01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Frank
*/
 public class Ejemplo01 {

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int entrada = 0;
    Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {

        System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");
        System.out.println("1. Crear lista");
        System.out.println("2. Insertar antes del nodo especifico");
        System.out.println("3. Vizualizar");
        System.out.println("4. Eliminar antes del nodo especifico");
        System.out.println("5. Salir del programa");
        entrada = opcion.nextInt();
    } while (entrada > 5 || entrada < 1);
       realizarAcciones(entrada);//aqui se ingresara un parametro para validar a que 
       opcion quieres ir 
}
  //con este metodo podras ingresar a las opciones mostradas en el menu puedes 
agregar las 
  que quieras.
//todo debe de seguir la misma estructura como te deje en el ejemplo dos
public static void realizarAcciones(int entrada) {
    List<String> ejemploLista = new ArrayList();
    switch (entrada) {
        case 1:
            int s2;
            do {
                System.out.println("Ingresa el primer nodo que se agregara: ");
                Scanner crear = new Scanner(System.in);
                String nodorecibido = crear.nextLine();
                ejemploLista.add(nodorecibido);
                System.out.println("¿Deseas ingresar otro nodo? S/N ");
                System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                s2 = s.nextInt();

            } while (s2 == 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            do {
                System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 2");
                System.out.println("¿Deseas volver a ingresar aqui? S/N ");
                System.out.println("Digita 1 =  Si Digita 2 = No ");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                s2 = s.nextInt();
            } while (s2 == 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(ejemploLista);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("el numero ingresado es 4");
            break;
    }
}}
```